# Set list as home page

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, administration, sitepages

I now have a list and I want this list to be the home page. I want the list to be the very first thing a user sees as soon as he/she lands on the subsite.

Searching the web I understand that in modern SP the only way to make a list as Home Page is to add a web part. Tried that but the result is far from being useful. The list is confined in a small section of the page and you need a lot of scrolling to navigate. It's not what i'd call user-friendly. If you ever tried that I am sure you know what I mean.

Does somebody have any kind of suggestion on how to have a visually satisfying representation of a list in home page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. If you want the SharePoint list to be the first thing users sees when they lands on the site, you will have to create a modern site page and add the list on the site page using "List" web part.

Check: [Use the List web part](https://support.microsoft.com/office/use-the-list-web-part-ef0a1b80-f8b3-443d-b04a-1e76c70b5537?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224).

Look and feel of SharePoint default web parts (like "List" web part) might not work for your requirements sometimes. Also, if you are showing many columns in the list web part, there will be horizontal scroll based on the number of columns you are showing and the resolution of laptop/desktop you are using.

Here are some suggestions you can try to make the list added on site page look good using SharePoint default functionalities:

1. If you are using "Communication site", you can create a page section that spans over the entire page, by adding a **full-width** column (not available in team site) AND add your list web part inside this section:

   [image]
2. In case of "Team site", you can use **One column** section to add the list web part.
3. You can use SharePoint JSON formatting to display list view/columns in customized way. For example, if you have long text column in the view, you can just show icon/button in the view and full column value will be shown on hover of the icon/button (to avoid horizontal scroll):

   - [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
   - [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
   - [List formatting samples](https://pnp.github.io/List-Formatting?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

---

**Additional Info**:

If SharePoint default web parts and functionalities are not working for your requirements, you can create custom web parts using SharePoint framework (SPFx):

1. [Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
2. [Use web parts with the full-width column](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/use-web-parts-full-width-column?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
3. [SPFx web part samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. My site is a Team Site and the default web part does not meet my needs. I started to work with SP a couple of months ago and I have no idea how to use SPFx. Is there a video tutorial you may suggest? Searching the web i see that i'm not the only one having this problem...yet could not find a video that shows how to do it.